# What are the Implications of using _GLIBCXX_CXX11_ABI to use pre-5.1 C++ ABI with C++ 11/14 features?

Tags: c++, gcc, abi

From [the manual:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)

> In the GCC 5.1 release libstdc++ introduced a new library ABI that includes new implementations of std::string and std::list. These changes were necessary to conform to the 2011 C++ standard which forbids Copy-On-Write strings and requires lists to keep track of their size.

It is possible to use the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro to control whter the library headers use the old or the new ABI, independently of which "-std" is being used.

I'd like to know what the implications of using this "compatibility ABI" would be?  I guess that the run-time performance of small-string operations will be impacted (negatively I assume), and that list-size access goes from O(1) (C11 ABI) to O(N) (compatibility ABI).

1. Are my guesses correct and can anyone elaborate?
2. Are there other implications which I have missed?  What about atomics and concurrency features?  Any impact?

Comment: When you say "C" do you mean "O(1)"?

Comment: I guess so.  I mean constant time.

Comment: I think the easiest would be to grep through the headers, there aren't that many occurences of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI.

Comment: edited  .. guess I gues the notation from my Calculus courses stuck more than my algorithms course

Comment: @Marc Glisse -- that's a good suggestion.  I still might miss an important implication caused by  a chain of dependency, so I'll be happy if someone with more expertise chimes in.

Comment: Although I'd like to see a comprehensive list, I think this is an overly broad question for SO. I don't think (haven't checked), this impacts atomics or concurrency. For one it isn't mentioned in the manual and second, there where no such things in the pre c++11 standard and I would not expect them to maintain compatibility to any experimental, non-standard c++0x versions of those features.

Comment: I don't agree with the overly broad characterization (obviously :) ).  But I think your remarks regarding concurrency are on-the-money.   However, if I combine your observations with the fact that I can use the "-std" flag independently of the ABI macro, that implies the macro could change the behavior of said functionality.  That said functionality was experimental pre-11 may imply a weak obligation to document such a change.   Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is actually answered by the manual itself:

> ... the choice of ABI to use is independent of the -std option used to
>   compile your code... This ensures that the -std does not change the ABI, so that it is
>   straightforward to link C++03 and C++11 code together.

Regarding the second question, I'm afraid it's hard to generalize the impact because it depends on how your code is using the standard library. Does it copy strings a lot? How often a list size is queried? Is the code multi-threaded?

Although atomics and concurrency were introduced in C++11's standard, I'd guess that stdlib++ copy-on-write mechanism already used a variation of it anyhow. Those implementations are typically thread-safe.

Perhaps one thing you didn't directly mention is the impact on other std components that depend on those behaviors, such as `list::splice`